# How does 'PathPrefix' work in 'gorilla.mux' library for Go?

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm playing around with the `gorilla.mux` library for Go.  I have the following configuration, but I cant figure out the URL to reach the `HelloWorldXml` method.

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/{name}.xml", HelloWorldXml).
           PathPrefix("/products/")
    router.HandleFunc("/hello/{name}", HelloWorld)
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8787",nil)
}
```

What would be the proper URL to use?  `http://localhost:8787/products/MyName.xml` returns a 404.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/{name}.xml", HelloWorldXml)
    subrouter := router.PathPrefix("/products/").Subrouter()
    //localhost/products/item.xml
    subrouter.HandleFunc("/{name}.xml", HelloWorldXmlHandler)
    router.HandleFunc("/hello/{name}", HelloWorld)
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8787",nil)
}
```

Comment: So, in order for the path prefix to work, you need to create a subrouter?  I guess I suspected that, but I never tried it.

Comment: Would appreciate some more context/info from the answer.